# are there any API's to read settings->general->usage page on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm new to ios, and im developing an "data tracking" app for iPhone. I am  struck with the main logic i.e to keep track of incoming and outgoing Bytes(numbers). Apps like "Dataman"are able track the data. Is there any API(even private will do) to read the settings->general->usage page on iPhone??

or there is any other way to track the data 
pls help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: no its not about the disk space. Its all about the data entering nd leaving the iPhone

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that gives you access to data from the 'Usage' page directly, but there are ways of getting at the information by other routes.

Have a look at this SO question ['Read network traffic bytes received and sent in objective c'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627013/read-network-traffic-bytes-received-and-sent-in-objective-c).